# Failed package in .NET

Tags: .net, ssis

I used Execute Processs Task to Extract files from zip folder.

In the Execute Process Task Editor, in process Tab, I set parameters like this:

```
Executeable:C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe
```

and in expression Tab:

```
Arguments:"e "+ @[User::ZipFilePath] +"\\"+ @[User::FnameZip]  +" -o+"
workingDirectory:@[User::UnzipFilePath]
```

When I run the SSIS package manually from within the BIDs environment, everything works fine, **But my problem is execute Package from .asp.net application**.

In .NET, my program failed, and return warning : No Archives found

What is wrong? Is it different setting parameter for execute package in .NET ?
 in log i get this message:
**The result of the expression ""e "+ @[User::ZipFilePath] +"\"+ @[User::FnameZip]  +" -o+"" on property "Arguments" cannot be written to the property. The expression was evaluated, but cannot be set on the property.**
and also for others my variable i have above error.

just if i set Argument with no variable and give the path like this:
D:\tempHolderZip\myfolder.zip , it work in .net

i found this 
[link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dipanb/archive/2011/07/14/you-may-see-weird-behavior-when-using-the-ssis-object-model-from-an-asp-net-application.aspx)
i try this also,but no result.

Comment: The ability to use a network share \\server\share is dependent upon the rights of the person/account of the user accessing it. Your domain account \company\bahar has rights to \\server\share *Who* is the user invoking your .NET application? Is it the end user or do you have embedded credentials in the package? Either way, you will need to verify whether the account that cannot run the SSIS package has sufficient privileges to View the Share, Read from the Share, Write to the share & possibly create a folder on the share. Finally, are you certain that WinRAR is installed on the client machine?

Comment: Try turning on logging for your SSIS package. There are a few things that could be causing this and having detailed log output can help you isolate the root of the problem.